# I keep getting the error message Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined when trying to get the mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm not sure why I keep getting the error 'cannot read property of clientX of undefined.

My understanding is that event.clientX should give me the x coordinate and event.clientY the Y coordinate.

Please can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

function getMousePos(event,canvas) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mx = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var my = event.clientY - rect.top;

    return { // the getMousePos function returns an object. It’s a factory
        x: mx,
        y: my,
    }
}

var mousePos = getMousePos(event, canvas);

console.log("Mouse position x = " + mousePos.x + " y = " + mousePos.y);
```

Comment: You aren't passing an actual mouse event into `getMousePos`. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event which may be helpful.

Comment: You are not using an Event at all. If you were, that `getMousePos` would have to be nested within the Event, and you would have to pass in the Event Object since the only thing passed to an EventListening function is the Event Object. Also, it won't do any good for an EventListening function to return  anything but false in certain cases. Just do stuff to the DOM Asynchronously inside the EventListening function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply pass a function an arbitrary `event` argument. You need to tell javascript that this function listens for a mouse event on the canvas. You do this by adding it as an [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp):

```js
var mousepos;
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  

        function getMousePos(event) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var mx = event.clientX - rect.left;
            var my = event.clientY - rect.top;
            mousepos = { 
                x: mx,
                y: my,
            }
            console.log(mousepos);
        }

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",getMousePos);
```

```html
<canvas id = "myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Whenever the user moves the mouse over the canvas, the `mouseOver` event is triggered. Since we have assigned `getMousePos` to listen to this event, javascript automatically passes the `event` parameter, and we can now read the relevant properties. Whenever the user moves their mouse, we `console.log()` the position.

Comment: Thanks that worked, do you know why the return key word didn't work in my original code? I expect that to give me the coordinates too according to the course I'm doing

Comment: It's because your function required an event argument, but it only gets passed that argument if you have the function inside an event listener. So in your case,`event` was undefined

Answer (score 0):

In this line :

```js
var mousePos = getMousePos(event, canvas);
```

You are passing a variable `event` that isn't defined. As redouglas said, you must pass `getMousePos` in an actual [mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event)

A correct script would be :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');


function getMousePos(event, canvas) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mx = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var my = event.clientY - rect.top;

    var mousePos = {
        x: mx,
        y: my,
    }
    console.log("Mouse position x = " + mousePos.x + " y = " + mousePos.y);
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var mx = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var my = event.clientY - rect.top;

    var mousePos = {
        x: mx,
        y: my,
    }
    console.log("Mouse position x = " + mousePos.x + " y = " + mousePos.y);
});
```

But as it depends on your needs, I suggest you to have a look on the linked MDN ressource.